# Import error on Windows10 with pytorch0.4

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pytorch, conda

### Discription

I am trying to install pytorch 0.4 on Windows10. 
My enviroment settings:
- Windows10
- cuda9.0
- python 3.6
- pytorch 0.4
- anaconda

I tried by using both `conda install -n myenv` and `pip install $path:whl` and both failed.

### Error

```
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\py3.6_pytorch0.4\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed:
```

I found the related a issue [#4518](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4518) under pytorch but answers under that issue do not work for me.

### What I have tried

- add all `conda` related path to environment path
- change the directory (`cd`)
- install `vs_runtime` under this `conda env`

None of those works.

**But** if I install `pytorch` under `conda`'s base environment, it works well.

So what's going on here?

---

### Update:

When we tried to install pytorch on windows, a lot of packages need to be installed at the same time. We can simply follow the steps on official website [link](https://pytorch.org/），for python 3.6 and cuda9.0 the installation command is as

```
    conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch
```

If we want to install former version of pytorch, we can assign the version, eg. 0.4 as

```
    conda install pytorch=0.4 torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create the new environment with conda, execute `conda install -c pytorch pytorch` to install *pytorch*.

`pip` does not work that well with external, non-Python dependencies. Not unlikely in your case path to the DLL is not set correctly (just a guess).

Comment: The parameter `-c` is very helpful. The official document shows it declares URL of installation, can someone explain more on how this works?

Comment: It tells conda which repository to use, in this case `pytorch`.